# Trying to find documentation for beanspeak

Tags: php, linux, beanstalkd

This may seem like a easy question but I'm trying to find documentation for Beanspeak (https://github.com/phalcongelist/beanspeak).  For those that don't know it's a C-extension for PHP 7 which allows PHP to talk to a beastalkd queue.

It claims to be the fastest solution and - since I shall be dealing with around 12 million very small messages an hour - I want to use it.

However the documentation is non-existant.  The official documentation simply tells you how to install it:

http://beanspeak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

This header file seems to define the various class methods but gives no clues as to the potential values of some parameters:

https://github.com/phalcongelist/beanspeak/blob/master/ext/beanspeak/job.zep.h

Despite spending several hours Googling around I've yet to find any documentation or even an example of how to use Beanspeak.  Have I missed something or is there really no documentation and the user is therefore left to figure it out ?

Comment: Not really sure this is a question suited for SO, no code etc. I personally would ditch that lib and look for something else with a decent documentation, maybe https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk

Comment: When I reviewed the various options I overlooked documentation as a criteria (doh!) - it's pretty much a given these days that a class should have good documentation, isn't it ?  I did look at when the various options were last updated and pheanstalk is no longer actively maintained.  I'm developing a large and complex system and need something that is regularly updated.